# Comunicação Bluetooth entre android e o arduino para interação com grbl

Tags: android, arduino

Como fazer `Android` depois conectar com `Arduino` através de um modulo Bluetooth para O `Arduino` receber dados. EU só preciso entender a parte do `Android` seria um Serial Bluetooth.

eu encontrei esse código na [Internet](https://dragaosemchama.com/2016/04/comunicacao-bluetooth-entre-arduino-e-android/) ele realiza se conexão com o modulo, bom gostaria de saber como faz para comunicar com o grbl 0.9 que está no `Arduino`, pois coloquei nesse código para enviar `m3` mas o `Arduino` não me responde.

Classe ConnectionThread

```
package br.com.dragaosemchama.supercounter;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ConnectionThread extends Thread{

    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    BluetoothServerSocket btServerSocket = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    String btDevAddress = null;
    String myUUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
    boolean server;
    boolean running = false;
    boolean isConnected = false;

    /*  Este construtor prepara o dispositivo para atuar como servidor.
     */
    public ConnectionThread() {

        this.server = true;
    }

    /*  Este construtor prepara o dispositivo para atuar como cliente.
        Tem como argumento uma string contendo o endereço MAC do dispositivo
    Bluetooth para o qual deve ser solicitada uma conexão.
     */
    public ConnectionThread(String btDevAddress) {

        this.server = false;
        this.btDevAddress = btDevAddress;
    }

    /*  O método run() contem as instruções que serão efetivamente realizadas
    em uma nova thread.
     */
    public void run() {

        /*  Anuncia que a thread está sendo executada.
            Pega uma referência para o adaptador Bluetooth padrão.
         */
        this.running = true;
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        /*  Determina que ações executar dependendo se a thread está configurada
        para atuar como servidor ou cliente.
         */
        if(this.server) {

            /*  Servidor.
             */
            try {

                /*  Cria um socket de servidor Bluetooth.
                    O socket servidor será usado apenas para iniciar a conexão.
                    Permanece em estado de espera até que algum cliente
                estabeleça uma conexão.
                 */
                btServerSocket = btAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Super Counter", UUID.fromString(myUUID));
                btSocket = btServerSocket.accept();

                /*  Se a conexão foi estabelecida corretamente, o socket
                servidor pode ser liberado.
                 */
                if(btSocket != null) {

                    btServerSocket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                /*  Caso ocorra alguma exceção, exibe o stack trace para debug.
                    Envia um código para a Activity principal, informando que
                a conexão falhou.
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
            }


        } else {

            /*  Cliente.
             */
            try {

                /*  Obtem uma representação do dispositivo Bluetooth com
                endereço btDevAddress.
                    Cria um socket Bluetooth.
                 */
                BluetoothDevice btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btDevAddress);
                btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(myUUID));

                /*  Envia ao sistema um comando para cancelar qualquer processo
                de descoberta em execução.
                 */
                btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                /*  Solicita uma conexão ao dispositivo cujo endereço é
                btDevAddress.
                    Permanece em estado de espera até que a conexão seja
                estabelecida.
                 */
                if (btSocket != null) {
                    btSocket.connect();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                /*  Caso ocorra alguma exceção, exibe o stack trace para debug.
                    Envia um código para a Activity principal, informando que
                a conexão falhou.
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
            }

        }

        /*  Pronto, estamos conectados! Agora, só precisamos gerenciar a conexão.
            ...
         */

        if(btSocket != null) {

            /*  Envia um código para a Activity principal informando que a
            a conexão ocorreu com sucesso.
             */
            this.isConnected = true;
            toMainActivity("---S".getBytes());

            try {

                /*  Obtem referências para os fluxos de entrada e saída do
                socket Bluetooth.
                 */
                input = btSocket.getInputStream();
                output = btSocket.getOutputStream();

                /*  Permanece em estado de espera até que uma mensagem seja
                recebida.
                    Armazena a mensagem recebida no buffer.
                    Envia a mensagem recebida para a Activity principal, do
                primeiro ao último byte lido.
                    Esta thread permanecerá em estado de escuta até que
                a variável running assuma o valor false.
                 */
                while(running) {

                    /*  Cria um byte array para armazenar temporariamente uma
                    mensagem recebida.
                        O inteiro bytes representará o número de bytes lidos na
                    última transmissão recebida.
                        O inteiro bytesRead representa o número total de bytes
                    lidos antes de uma quebra de linha. A quebra de linha
                    representa o fim da mensagem.
                     */
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytes;
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    /*  Lê os bytes recebidos e os armazena no buffer até que
                    uma quebra de linha seja identificada. Nesse ponto, assumimos
                    que a mensagem foi transmitida por completo.
                     */
                    do {
                        bytes = input.read(buffer, bytesRead+1, 1);
                        bytesRead+=bytes;
                    } while(buffer[bytesRead] != '\n');

                    /*  A mensagem recebida é enviada para a Activity principal.
                     */
                    toMainActivity(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, bytesRead-1));

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                /*  Caso ocorra alguma exceção, exibe o stack trace para debug.
                    Envia um código para a Activity principal, informando que
                a conexão falhou.
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
                toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
                this.isConnected = false;
            }
        }

    }

    /*  Utiliza um handler para enviar um byte array à Activity principal.
        O byte array é encapsulado em um Bundle e posteriormente em uma Message
    antes de ser enviado.
     */
    private void toMainActivity(byte[] data) {

        Message message = new Message();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("data", data);
        message.setData(bundle);
        MainActivity.handler.sendMessage(message);
    }

    /*  Método utilizado pela Activity principal para transmitir uma mensagem ao
     outro lado da conexão.
        A mensagem deve ser representada por um byte array.
     */
    public void write(byte[] data) {

        if(output != null) {
            try {

                /*  Transmite a mensagem.
                 */
                output.write(data);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            /*  Envia à Activity principal um código de erro durante a conexão.
             */
            toMainActivity("---N".getBytes());
        }
    }

    /*  Método utilizado pela Activity principal para encerrar a conexão
     */
    public void cancel() {

        try {

            running = false;
            this.isConnected = false;
            btServerSocket.close();
            btSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        running = false;
        this.isConnected = false;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return this.isConnected;
    }
}
```

Activity Principal

```
package br.com.dragaosemchama.supercounter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /* Definição dos objetos que serão usados na Activity Principal
        statusMessage mostrará mensagens de status sobre a conexão
        counterMessage mostrará o valor do contador como recebido do Arduino
        connect é a thread de gerenciamento da conexão Bluetooth
     */
    static TextView statusMessage;
    static TextView counterMessage;
    ConnectionThread connect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Link entre os elementos da interface gráfica e suas
            representações em Java.
         */
        statusMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);
        counterMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterMessage);

        /* Teste rápido. O hardware Bluetooth do dispositivo Android
            está funcionando ou está bugado de forma misteriosa?
            Será que existe, pelo menos? Provavelmente existe.
         */
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            statusMessage.setText("Que pena! Hardware Bluetooth não está funcionando :(");
        } else {
            statusMessage.setText("Ótimo! Hardware Bluetooth está funcionando :)");
        }

        /* A chamada do seguinte método liga o Bluetooth no dispositivo Android
            sem pedido de autorização do usuário. É altamente não recomendado no
            Android Developers, mas, para simplificar este app, que é um demo,
            faremos isso. Na prática, em um app que vai ser usado por outras
            pessoas, não faça isso.
         */
        btAdapter.enable();

        /* Definição da thread de conexão como cliente.
            Aqui, você deve incluir o endereço MAC do seu módulo Bluetooth.
            O app iniciará e vai automaticamente buscar por esse endereço.
            Caso não encontre, dirá que houve um erro de conexão.
         */
        connect = new ConnectionThread("00:16:13:19:43:54");
        connect.start();

        /* Um descanso rápido, para evitar bugs esquisitos.
         */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            /* Esse método é invocado na Activity principal
                sempre que a thread de conexão Bluetooth recebe
                uma mensagem.
             */
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            byte[] data = bundle.getByteArray("data");
            String dataString= new String(data);

            /* Aqui ocorre a decisão de ação, baseada na string
                recebida. Caso a string corresponda à uma das
                mensagens de status de conexão (iniciadas com --),
                atualizamos o status da conexão conforme o código.
             */
            if(dataString.equals("---N"))
                statusMessage.setText("Ocorreu um erro durante a conexão D:");
            else if(dataString.equals("---S"))
                statusMessage.setText("Conectado :D");
            else {

                /* Se a mensagem não for um código de status,
                    então ela deve ser tratada pelo aplicativo
                    como uma mensagem vinda diretamente do outro
                    lado da conexão. Nesse caso, simplesmente
                    atualizamos o valor contido no TextView do
                    contador.
                 */
                counterMessage.setText(dataString);
            }

        }
    };

    /* Esse método é invocado sempre que o usuário clicar na TextView
        que contem o contador. O app Android transmite a string "restart",
        seguido de uma quebra de linha, que é o indicador de fim de mensagem.
     */
  //Está parte que alterei para enviar m3 para testar
    public void restartCounter(View view) {
        connect.write("m3".getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla, se você teve alguma tentativa falha, tente postar a parte ao qual você teve dificuldade.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: @WictorChaves alterei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o a solução para meu problema que neste código [Bluetooth comunicação serial](https://github.com/Sash0k/bluetooth-spp-terminal), com ele consigo comunicar certo no meu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a comunicação entre o bluetooth do arduino e o Android, você vai precisar de um módulo de bluetooth no seu arduino, recomendo o HC-06.

A conexão entre o Arduino e o é HC-06 simples, Todas as informações que o Arduino precisar transmitir ao Android deverão passar antes pelo módulo Bluetooth HC-06 e vice versa. Ou seja talvez o seu problema seja que as modificações feitas com/pelo grbl não estajam passando pelo módulo bluetooth.

Outra coisa, é Que precisamos obter permissão para utilizar o dispositivo Bluetooth do Android. Fazemos isso adicionando essas linhas ao Manifest.xml, dentro da tag .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

e também acho válido testar se tudo que você quer fazer com seu arduino estão funcionando corretamente. Tente trabalhar com cada coisa separadamente, por exemplo, primeiro faça algo com o grbl, depois com o bluetooth... Assim já detectei vários erros que eu mesmo estava fazendo utilizando errado.
Se você consegue trabalhar com o bluetooth e com o grbl bem, separadamente, não será problema utilizá los em um único projeto

Answer (score -1):

Rodolfo, Eu agora estou utilizando o Esp32 para os projetos com arduino e bluetooth. Para fazer a aplicação no android e ios, eu tive como base os códigos fontes da Nordic (fabricante do Esp32). O mais simples -> [Android-nRF-UART](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/Android-nRF-UART) 
Mesmo que seu arduino não for o Esp32, sugiro dar uma olhada e alterar o UUID para sua aplicação.

Comment: Legal, mas não consegui testar, ele scaneia mas não mostra nenhum dispositivo Bluetooth.

Comment: Este código é para o Esp32, necessita alterar as UUID. Dica nos Android mais recentes, para fazer o scan necessita ligar a localização (GPS) antes , estranho mais é assim !!!

Comment: Favor procurar na net exemplos de como seu código pode checar isto, antes de procurar os dispositivos